# How to add border on img-responsive or img-circle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image with 450x450 size which is automatically resized because using img-responsive and img-circle. The problem is that the radius border is always trying to border the original size (450x450).

```css
.img-circle {  
  border-radius:50%;
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x450" class="img-responsive img-circle pad-img" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x450" class="img-responsive img-circle pad-img" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x450" class="img-responsive img-circle pad-img" alt="" />
</div>
```

the actual result is like this:
http://prntscr.com/pji0u1

Comment: Your code works fine for me; is it possible that some other css is effecting the outcome? https://jsfiddle.net/jxLcnuq8/

Comment: Works fine here too, perhaps some css is overwriting the rule. Find what is overwriting og use !important; to force rule

Comment: thx for tips guys , somehow i cant figure out what is overwriting the rule, but right now , adding padding: 0px can fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You required padding. if you dont want then you can add padding 0 will help. Try this.

```css
.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid red;
  padding: 20px;
//padding: 0px //if you don't want padding.
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" class="img-responsive img-circle pad-img" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, the padding: 0px is what i was looking for ;)

Comment: Great that helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify explicitly the size of the picture, and after draw border. 
I added HTML and CSS code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2916450/pexels-photo-2916450.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="img-responsive img-circle pad-img" alt="" />
</div>
```

Css:

```
body {
  background-color: gray;
}


.img-circle {
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.pad-img {
  image: cover;
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

[Screenshot with the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpEsg.png)

Comment: it will work if we use only one image, but if we have more than one , we cant declare width and height sizes because of responsive behavior, so instead of circle we get an oval image, Anyway thx for the tips.